# jQuery: how to use base64 image object as list-style-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, base64

I have a base64 encoded png stored in JS object `my.photo` .

I intend to use it as list-style-image but I am not sure how to do it. I tried the following:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+my.photo;
$('li').css({'list-style-image': image});
```

This did not work. The firbug console shows the following style applied:

```
element.style {
    list-style-image: url("[object HTMLImageElement]");
}
```

How can I fix this using JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this instead:

```
$('li').css({'list-style-image': 'url(' + image.src + ')'});
```

Comment: @NabilKadimi. Yes, that's better.

Comment: There's always better!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Credits: Duvdevan 
$('li').css({'list-style-image': 'url(' + image.src + ')'});
```

Since this is JavaScript and that [you can do the same thing in many ways](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html):

```js
$('li').css('list-style-image', 'url(' + image.src + ')');
```

```js
$('li').css('list-style-image', 'url(♥)'.replace('♥', image.src));
```

---

In your question, you don't need all that code, `new Image()`, `image.src =`, ...

```
$('li').css(
    'listStyleImage',
    'url(data:image/png;base64,♥)'.replace('♥', my.photo)
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are passing the entire object as parameter rather than just the string (you don't need to create an object here actually). You also forgot the `url("..")` part. So, with rest of your code the last line should be:

```
$('li').css({'list-style-image': 'url("' + image.src + '")'});
```